# Does `shutdown -P now` safely unmount a USB drive mounted to `/dev/sdb1`?

Tags: mount, shutdown

I typically unmount my USB drive (using `umount`)  from `/dev/sdb1` before I shutdown my computer but if I shut it down using `shutdown -P now` and then restart it, the drive is no longer mounted.

Is this a safe way to unmount the drive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, all mounted drives are automatically unmounted during shutdown.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I would upvote but I don't have quite enough rep yet.

Comment: I'm guessing this holds true whether any of the following commands are issued: reboot, shutdown, halt, poweroff ?

Comment: @dtmland, al disks are umounted before shutting down - after killing all user processes. Now, if the system starts again (as in the case of reboot) they can be mounted again on boot - or not, depending on configuration.